# Pi hole and independent wifi access point

Tags: networking, dhcp, pi-hole

I'm currently using pihole also as DHCP server (i.e. I deactivated DHCP server on my router and let my pi serving IPs). My pi is connected solely via ethernet (I disabled wifi via `/boot/config.txt`).

Now I would like to create an "internal" network using my pi as a wifi access point, i.e.: I would like to create a separate network (that is within tihs network it should not be possible to access internet).

Is it possible? How can I do?

Comment: So to understand what you are asking, do you want to create 2 wifi access points?

Comment: Not exactly. I already have a router that is also the access point for the "normal" network (the wan connected to the internet). The pi is used as DHCP server to this network. I want to add a network to my setup using my pi as an access point. Within this new network internet should be unreachable.

Comment: This is possible, but there isn't any detail in your post about _why_ you might want to do this, and that makes a recommendation or answer difficult. Suggest explaining your use case. Alternatively without knowing your requirements or networking knowledge, you could use another Pi (or similar) to run OpenWRT which makes such things easy: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-quick-start/basic_wifi